# I cannot get text and other content on my webpage to appear to the right of a logo image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and would like for the menu and logo on the left to remain stationary while I add content to the right of them, but whenever I add anything it pushes them around, I made a post earlier and managed to fix the menu (I think), but the logo still appears to have an invisible barrier horizontally across the site. Here is my code thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>

<center> 
    <h1 style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">music etc.</h1>
    </center>

<div class=“panel”>
<left>
    <img src=img/glassparklogodraft1yellow.png height=215 width=215>
    </left>

</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class=“panel”>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.vertical-menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: white;
}
div.spacer
{
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0px;
    line-height: 0;
}
div {
    border: 0px solid black;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    background-color: white;

</style>
</div>

<body>

<div class="vertical-menu">
  <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=main.html>home</a>
  <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=magazine.html>magazine</a>
  <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=visual.html>visual content</a>
  <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=audio.html>audio</a>
  <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=contact.html>contact</a>
</div>


</body>

<body>
<center>
<p>2nd floor - the fabled sound<p>

<a href=gpmaudio/2ndfloorthefabledsound.zip download>

  <img src=img/fabledsoundcover.png width=200 height=200>

</a>
</center>
</body>

<div class=“spacer”></div>

<body>
<center>
<p>2nd floor - the lebron bonus<p>

<a href=gpmaudio/2ndfloorthelebronbonus.zip download>

  <img src=img/lebronbonuscover.jpg width=200 height=200>

</a>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I suggest getting rid of those `<center>` and `<left>` tags? They are deprecated and the support is spotty, behaviour might be inconsistent across browsers. Things that are about "presentation" should live in CSS. What you are trying to achieve can be achieved with css [`float` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

Comment: Another option is to wrap the logo and the menu into a div with fixed width and 100vh height.

Comment: The HTML is invalid. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp

Comment: I got rid of <left>, although it made my header off to the side when I got rid of center... but that's not my biggest concern, I just want the menu and logo to be on the left, and content to be directly to the right of them.

Comment: Where do I put the float property? I breifly messed around with it, but couldn't figure it out.